# Where can I test a path?

Tags: folders, path

I have tto check a path like "volume1:FTPRoot:StenRoot:Stnp00:A12:B38:f000031913". Is there an easy place where I can paste this to unsure me that this path is valid ?

*PS / I can follow it manually, but I want to automate this...*

Comment: Are you good with shell scripting in the terminal app? You'll need a tool to convert : to / as well as map the volume to /Volumes (assuming all the files actually have a valid volume name for the first entry) There are about 5 things you'll need to learn to make a program to automate this... Without knowing your edge cases - it's hard to know how robust your tool needs to be - this isn't ever a valid path as written so you have to process the input before testing validity of the path.

Comment: @mike : thanks for your help. I will go with the idea of christian for the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift + Command + G (Go To Folder) can help you. This [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) has other handy keyboard shortcuts in the Finder. Hope this helps.

Comment: The fact that this path leads to another disk than the startup one seems to block this command.

Comment: Ok, if I open any folder on the right disk, and choose that command menu, then your trick works. Thanks.